# defining a scala function1 for use by java has wrong types

Tags: scala, generics

The problem can be summarised as follows:

I have a class that defines several methods to be called from java. one of them has a signature like:

```
import java.lang.{Double => JDouble}

def compute(x: Double, fun: Function1[Double,Double]) = ???
```

or

```
def compute(x: Double, fun: Double => Double) = ???
```

when i use javap on any of them, it looks like this:

```
Double compute(double, scala.Function1<java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object>)
```

if I use the following aliasing

```
 import java.lang.{Double => JDouble}
 def compute(x: Double, fun: JDouble => JDouble) =
```

it looks correct with javap

```
public Double compute( double, scala.Function1<java.lang.Double, java.lang.Double>);
```

Why is this?

Comment: See https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4214 and lots of other tickets like SI-4948, SI-4403, SI-5255, et al.

Answer (score 1):

In Scala Double extends AnyVal. When you javap this function the nearest super class finds and in case AnyVal the nearest Java super class is Object.